# python Mac OS : os.path.getsize returns different value than du -ks?

Tags: python, macos, directory, os.walk, du

When comparing the size of a directory with Unix and python, I have slightly different results (5% smaller with "disk usage"). Why ?
(all my subfolders are readable; I work under Mac OSX Mountain lion, python version 2.7.2)

Here is my code :

```
import os, sys
from commands import getstatusoutput

def get_size(start_path = '.'):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    return total_size/1024

def get_size2(start_path = '.'):
    cmd = "du -ks "+start_path    # result in blocks of 1024 bytes
    code_err, output = getstatusoutput(cmd)
    return int(output.split()[0])

print get_size()
# 306789
print get_size2()
# 321328
```

Thanking you by advance for your answers,

Eric.

Comment: Summing the byte sizes and dividing by 1024 is not the same as getting the total number of 1024 blocks used(Think having 1024 files of one byte. They use a total of 1024 bytes = 1 block, but actually each file uses a 1024 block, so the real space used is 1024^2). Try to modify `getsize` to compute the number of 1024 blocks used *for each file*, the result should be the same.

Comment: Style note: The `commands` module is deprecated. In your case you should really use `subprocess.check_output`

Comment: You're right.I guessed that my machine blocksize was 4096, si I replaced the line total_size += by total_size += (os.path.getsize(fp)+4096)/4096 * 4\n\nThe results are the same for some directories, but still little lower for other ones (here: 316140)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, `du` gives you the amount of storage the data is occupying on the disk while a lot of other ways to measure the data will give you the size of the data.

Why is this not the same?

- Sometimes data can be stored very efficiently and needs less space on storage than its original size.  This can happen if you have got *sparse files* or *hard links*.  While these two are common on Unix*ish file systems there might be other things, depending on the weirdness of your file systems.
- Sometimes data needs more space on disk than it has originally in size.  This is rather normal due to the fact that all file systems order their file data in blocks and data doesn't always come in multiples of the block size.  This means that some part of the last block is typically wasted (i. e. occupied but not used).