# os.path.getsize vs du -sh on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, du

I want to measure size of single file in MB in python.

Using python:

```
def get_size_in_mb(filepath):
    size_in_bytes = os.path.getsize(filepath)
    size_in_mb = size_in_bytes // (1024*1024)
    return size_in_mb
```

Using bash:

```
du -sh Ue3Amb-A-P0.mp4
```

Second method gives `112` MB and first `103` MB.

As I understand based on this answer difference can't be so large:
[python Mac OS : os.path.getsize returns different value than du -ks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913508/python-mac-os-os-path-getsize-returns-different-value-than-du-ks)

Comment: Please stick to the internationally agreed SI units system - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units Please use capital **B** for **bytes** and lower case **b** for **bits**, so one megabyte is 1MB, one gigabyte is 1GB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte) and one gigabit is 1Gb (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit). Your use of `mb` implies millibits! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A file may have extended attributes. This is additional data associated with the file which is not part of its normal data.

The size of the normal data is what's reported by the `st_size` field of the `struct stat` structure filled in by the `stat()` system call. However, the total size of the file, including both the normal data and the extended attributes, is included in the `st_blocks` field.

You can read [the source code for macOS's `du` implementation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-272.220.1/du/du.c.auto.html). For files less that 2TB in size, it uses the block size of the file.

I assume that Python is using `st_size`.

You can see the sizes of the extended attributes by applying `ls -l@s` to the file.